# While loops with nested if statements; Eliminating multiple prints and exiting the loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

One crummy thing that happens is "rock" will sometimes not produce any results. Sometimes I will play the game and it will work just fine and other times the loop will end and zero games would have been played.
If you could please use code within the program so I can learn where my mistakes were and then after that I would appreciate some tweaking to make it efficient. I think the order of nested conditionals within while loops is what I am struggling with? Please excuse the language.

```
"""Rock, Paper, Scissors Exercise 8"""
game= input("Are you ready to ply? Y or N: ").capitalize()
user1 = input("What's your name? ")
user2 = input("What's your name? ")
p1 = input(user1 + ": Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").lower()
p2 = input(user2 + ": Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").lower()
p1_count=0
p2_count=0
games_played = 0

while game == "Y":
    if p1 == "rock":
        if p2 == "rock":
            print("It\'s a tie!")
            game = input("Are you ready to ply? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            p2_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "scissors":
            print(user2 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to play? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "paper":
            print(user1 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to play? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p2_count += 1
            games_played += 1
    elif p1 == "scissors":
        if p2 == "scissors":
            print("It\'s a tie!")
            game = input("Are you ready to play? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            p2_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "paper":
            print(user2 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to play? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "rock":
            print(user1 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to play? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            games_played += 1
    elif p1 == "paper":
        if p2 == "paper":
            print("It\'s a tie!")
            game = input("Are you ready to ply? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "rock":
            print(user2 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to ply? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "scissors":
            print(user1 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to ply? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            games_played += 1


print("Thank you " + user1 + " and " + user2 + " for playing this classic fucking 
game!")
print("With " + str(games_played) + " games played, " + "the score was " + user1 + " 
with " + str(p1_count) + " and " + user2 + " with " + str(p2_count))
```

Comment: Way too much text sorry; can you reduce it to the pertinent points please?

Comment: I bolded the relevant bits. Consider reducing/removing all the surrounding text so folks have less to read through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
game= input("Are you ready to ply? Y or N: ").capitalize()
user1 = input("What's your name? ")
user2 = input("What's your name? ")

p1_count=0
p2_count=0
games_played = 0

while game == "Y":
    p1 = input(user1 + ": Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").lower()
    p2 = input(user2 + ": Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").lower()
    if p1 == "rock":
        if p2 == "rock":
            print("It\'s a tie!")
            game = input("Are you ready to ply? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            p2_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "scissors":
            print(user2 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to play? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "paper":
            print(user1 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to play? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p2_count += 1
            games_played += 1
    elif p1 == "scissors":
        if p2 == "scissors":
            print("It\'s a tie!")
            game = input("Are you ready to play? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            p2_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "paper":
            print(user2 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to play? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "rock":
            print(user1 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to play? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p2_count += 1
            games_played += 1
    elif p1 == "paper":
        if p2 == "paper":
            print("It\'s a tie!")
            game = input("Are you ready to ply? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "rock":
            print(user2 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to ply? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p1_count += 1
            games_played += 1
        elif p2 == "scissors":
            print(user1 + ", you got beat mothafucka!")
            game = input("Are you ready to ply? Y or N: ").capitalize()
            p2_count += 1
            games_played += 1


print("Thank you " + user1 + " and " + user2 + " for playing this classic fucking game!")
print("With " + str(games_played) + " games played, " + "the score was " + user1 + " with " + str(p1_count) + " and " + user2 + " with " + str(p2_count))
```

Just put these two lines (`p1 and p2`) inside the `while` loop, and you're done!

What happened in here is that, you didn't take input for the next execution of `while` loop. So the values of `p1` and `p2` remained constant.

So, This will work now, Corrected some mistakes.. (last `elif` statement in the 2nd and 3rd `elif` statements)